# UnicodeEncodeError: unsure of error

Tags: python, python-twitter

I keep getting this error while trying to execute my program. Please note that I am using Python Twitter Tools and will not be posting my full code as it contains information related to my Twitter.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Programming\Code\Twitter App\Twitter.py", line 57, in <module>
Main()
File "E:\Programming\Code\Twitter App\Twitter.py", line 32, in Main
Timeline()
File "E:\Programming\Code\Twitter App\Twitter.py", line 53, in Timeline
print ("(%s) @%s %s" % (status["created_at"], status["user"]["screen_name"], status["text"]))
File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f62d' in position 55: character maps to <undefined>
```

My code is as follows:

```
while True:

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # request my home timeline
    # twitter API docs: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    statuses = twitter.statuses.home_timeline(count = 50)

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # loop through each of my statuses, and print its content
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    for status in statuses:
        print ("(%s) @%s %s" % (status["created_at"], status["user"]["screen_name"], status["text"]))
```

I am severely confused as to why I am getting this error. If you need more code, please ask for it, but I will be hiding the personal information.

EDIT:
I also seem to get this error occasionally before any tweets are displayed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Programming\Code\Twitter App\Twitter.py", line 57, in <module>
Main()
File "E:\Programming\Code\Twitter App\Twitter.py", line 32, in Main
Timeline()
File "E:\Programming\Code\Twitter App\Twitter.py", line 53, in Timeline
print ("(%s) @%s %s" % (status["created_at"], status["user"]["screen_name"], status["text"]))
File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 66-70: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: recommend to go and watch this -> http://bit.ly/unipain

Comment: @wim: that won't help all that much to fix the pain that is the Windows console, and the way Python prints to it.